# Page turn/flip animation in Android?

Tags: android

Hi all, do we have page flip/turn animation in android?
I have several images, and i want to flip images on button click. With page turn/flip animation.
Please guide me to achieve it.

Comment: Do you want the whole pag to flip or only the corner like in eBooks?

Comment: @shishir.bobby hi iam face this problem any help please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 3D flip rotation

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

that turns the whole page around it's y-axis.

Comment: This isn't really a 3D flip. Simply rotating around the y-axis doesn't give a believable 3D rotation. See my answer (bottom) or checkout: https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition

Comment: @ Mathias Lin: What if I want the page to curl at its half like in iPhone. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/6096894/2311051

Comment: I have gone through Curl effect as well as flip effect in android where pages of a book are turned but what i need is turn effect on book means when we have a book with first and last cover as hard bound then the turning style will be different from curl and flip effect.

So please can any one tell me how to implement this and any supporting links or tutorials or examples (are appreciated )

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

None of these are really 3D flips. The depth animation is necessary to get that 3D feel (as in the iOS flip view transition). For a nice implementation of 3D flips in android, take a look at this googlecode: https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition

A video is here too: http://youtu.be/52mXHqX9f3Y

Answer (score 2):

You can use a View Flipper. You can add 2 imageViews to ViewFlipper and keep changing the images in the 2 ImageViews. There are ways to completely flip the contents. Please let me know if you need that.

Comment: hey,
acually i hv 40 images
and on click on lower right of screen, it should turn above and next image show up, similary, if i click on  upper left of screen, previous image should come back.


yes sure i need it man

Comment: I have gone through Curl effect as well as flip effect in android where pages of a book are turned but what i need is turn effect on book means when we have a book with first and last cover as hard bound then the turning style will be different from curl and flip effect.

So please can any one tell me how to implement this and any supporting links or tutorials or examples (are appreciated )

Thank you