# Page turn/flip with button click for android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on page curl/turn animation with button click and I couldn't able to do it. Because I am new to Android and I searched a lot  through Google, someone please share your knowledge with  the example code for the animation

I am working on a sign-in page with  username,email as text-view elements with edit text boxes, and Signin and Register are the two buttons

When I click the Register button the page should turn/flip to  a new Register page and for signin button It should show an Alert dialog after submitting the credentials

Help is always appreciated, Thanks.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can have as many layout (.xml) pages as you'd like. When you desire to use one simply call `setContentView(signin)` or something alike.
2. You need to learn to explore your options before you post a question, thus creating two threads about the same topic. Look through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362683/page-turn-flip-animation-in-android).

Comment: thanks a lot, I got some Idea,but in which way we store  two layouts and apply flip animation in the activity

Comment: @Raghav explore the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) a little bit and come back with more specific issues. This stuff is 101 and there are multiple tutorials out there to achieve them all. If you want some references to certain tutorial material be more specific.