# How to display the image from page curl to another view?

Tags: android, curl, opengl-es, android-widget, android-view

I am working with Harism Page Curl(Open GL) 
https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl. Its working fine now. Here I want to display the image on the page curl to another view on a click. Could you help me, if it is possible..

Answer (score 0):

You have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779862/how-can-i-show-page-curl-animation-on-click-of-the-button-in-android) for page curl on click event? It is also helpful for me.

Comment: Hi @hardik joshi thanks for your reply. I already checked this. It tolds about the Margins of the curlView. But I want to click the image on the curl and display it in to another view after the click. Could you please help me..