# Android: page curl effect like iphone

Tags: android, animation, curl, opengl-es

I want to create half page curl animation effect as shown in image:

[image]

I've used code from https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/ , but it turns whole page. I just only want half page curl effect as shown in image.

Comment: So you want us to do your coding? That's not going to happen. Try yourself and when you come up with any errors, we'll help you solve them.

Comment: But i have not any idea to start coding for this.

Comment: _I've used code from_ so show us.

Comment: Ok, now i have updated a link in my question, you can see code.

Comment: @user609293: We're interested, but not *that* interested, in the library you're using. What we'd really like to see, is *your own* code.

Comment: I do not have any code. I have given link only for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to modify my implementation. It's not 3D but a nice 2D simulation using the plain canvas: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

If you enbale the debug mode you will see how it works and modifying the curl plane should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to change part of code at updatePageRects() method in CurlRenderer class:

```
mPageRectRight.bottom = (mPageRectRight.bottom - mViewRect.height() * mMargins.bottom)/5;
```